# How to run the cpp samples in openvino

Tags: c++, intel, openvino

I am using openvino_2019.2.242 and trying to run the cpp samples in the same. Please guide me with the complete steps to build the sample applications. As an example can you provide the command to run classification sample async . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the sample applications , run the build_samples_msvc.bat batch file:

> < INSTALL_DIR >\inference_engine\samples\build_samples_msvc.bat

Open terminal

```
 cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_2019.2.242\inference_engine\samples
 build_samples_msvc.bat
```

The sample applications binaries are in the

```
 C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_build\intel64\Release
```

directory.

---

***The below 3 steps are optional***

```
 cd C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_build

 select samples.sln

 Build -> Build Solution
```

---

This will create the executable files at the below location

```
 C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_build\intel64\Release
```

To run

(for eg: classification_sample_async)

```
 cd C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\inference_engine_samples_build\intel64\Release

 classification_sample_async.exe -m C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\ir\FP32\classification\squeezenet\1.1\caffe\squeezenet1.1.xml -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_2019.1.122\deployment_tools\demo\car.png" -labels <PATH_TO_LABEL_FILE>\squeezenet1.1.labels -d CPU
```